# Jenkins NuGet Restore - Response Code 500

Tags: c#, jenkins, nuget, nuget-package-restore

Our company has been having some issues with some Jenkins jobs failing or not even executing so I decided to start with a clean slate and test from my local machine.

I downloaded / installed Jenkins to my local laptop. My company has an internal nuget source and that's where I'm receiving the 500 internal server error. I can restore the nuget packages from the nuget.org source just fine.

I've tried updating the nuget.config in a few areas to include my user / password for our internal nuget gallery.

I'm not very much up to speed with what some of these error messages could indicate with regards to a Jenkins job. Are my credentials even being used or does the 500 mean that our internal gallery isn't even accessible via this Jenkins job. I'm able to navigate to the internal gallery manually and that works just fine.

According to the job run output it's trying to access the following feeds with these config files:

```
NuGet Config files used:
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
    C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config

Feeds used:
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
    https://nugetgallery.<company name>.com/api/v2
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
```

I've modified both of those nuget.config files to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="<internal nuget gallery name>" value="https://nugetgallery.<company name>.com/api/v2" />
    <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\" />
  </packageSources>
  
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <NugetGallery>
      <add key="Username" value="<my username>" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="<my password>" />
    </NugetGallery>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="False" />
    <add key="automatic" value="False" />
  </packageRestore>
  <bindingRedirects>
    <add key="skip" value="False" />
  </bindingRedirects>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Error 500 means the connection completed including an authentication and the server got an error while processing the request.  The server did not stop executing since it sent a response back to the client.

Comment: @jdweng is there anything you can provide that I can take back to my boss as far as an area for us to start looking to see what could be causing the problem?

Comment: I would look at the event viewer on the server to see if there are any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I've found my own answer.

You have to make sure that the key name for your internal nuget feed is the same name that you use inside the `<PackageSourceCredentials>` tag.

So since the tag inside `<PackageSourceCredentials>` is **NugetGallery** I had to change `<add key="<internal nuget gallery name>" value="https://nugetgallery.<company name>.com/api/v2" />` to `<add key="NugetGallery" value="https://nugetgallery.<company name>.com/api/v2" />`